# For nvarchar greater than 4000 characters which one is better chunking the string to chunk with 4KB in IN_ROW_DATA or save in LOB_DATA?

Tags: sql-server, database

As you know the size of page in SQL Server is **8KB**, and there are three *allocation units*: *IN_ROW_DATA*, *LOB_DATA* and *ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA*.

I should save a string between 1000 and 20000 characters in *nvarchar* datatype, and the speed of read from DB is so important.

I chunked the string into segments with *4KB* size to save in DB, but I'm not sure which one is better chunking the string and save in *IN_ROW_DATA* or save in *LOB_DATA*?

Comment: You can just define the column as nvarchar(max). SQL server will determine the storage based on the real length.

Comment: I wouldn't go through the hassle of chunking this. That is way more effort than you should bother with. nvarchar(max) will store the data in row when possible. Reassembling chunks of data is very likely going to take more time when reading then letting sql server deal with it. Be careful, you seem to be on the verge of premature optimization which is the practice of making non-standard design decisions to deal with a performance problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: SQL Server s highly specialised system for reading and storing data. All low level performance improvements that can be made (for data storage and retrieval) has been made a decade ago. If you want to improve performance, save your time and money in writing "chunking" code and buy an extra RAM stick for your server.